# Put files already in S3 in a folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I used `aws s3 sync myfolder my-bucket` to copy files from EC2 to a bucket in s3. Now, they're loose (not in a folder). The usual mkdir and mv commands don't seem to be available - how can I make a folder and put my files into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would be to to sync again, but this time with the folder name which you want (it will be created automatically):

```
aws s3 sync myfolder s3://my-bucket/my-folder-on-s3
```

The other way would be `mv` with `--recursive` option:

```
 aws s3 mv s3://my-bucket s3://my-bucket/my-folder-on-s3  --recursive
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to copy them to S3 would be:

```
aws s3 sync localdir s3://my-bucket
```

If you wish to move files around an Amazon S3 bucket, use:

```
aws s3 mv s3://my-bucket/object1.txt s3://my-bucket/folder1/
```

Comment: how do i make folder1? or will it automatically be created with the mv command?

Comment: Folders do not actually existing in Amazon S3. Just pretend that they will be automatically created and it will work the way you expect.